# How to know my post request came from my phonegap/cordova app in a PHP server

Tags: php, ajax, cordova, security

Let's say I have a Phonegap / cordova app and I want to make requests to my server with POSTs and GETs throught AJAX.

How can I secure my php file to do only if the post come from my app. E.G.

```
if($_POST["key"]==$secret_key_got_from_server) {
   // Do the things
}
```

I wanted to create a secure unique key with openssl, but if I hardcode it in the code to send it throught AJAX, anyone could just decompile my source code and get the key and do whatever he wants.

How could I make sure my post come from my phonegap app, or how can I securily code that key/token ?

I'm not quite sure if this question should be here or in security SE.

Comment: Any reason you couldn't use something like Firebase?  It generates unique tokens for each device that you can verify against Firebase to ensure that it comes from a mobile, and you have the added bonus that you can send mobile notifications. P.S. It won't absolutely ensure that miscreants won't try to get your data, but it will raise the effort to the point that only the most determined will try.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How could I make sure my post come from my phonegap app, or how can I securily code that key/token ?

[You can't](https://paragonie.com/blog/2016/03/client-authenticity-is-not-server-s-problem). Full stop. Reverse engineering exists in the world, and that genie has been out of the bottle for at least 40 years.

Ask yourself, "Why is it necessary to ensure that the data can *only* come from my app?" You're very likely trying to solve the wrong problem.

Comment: Wow that link was really usefull and really helped me learned more about soft architecture. Thank you !

Comment: @Carlos2W I'm really happy to hear that. Best of luck with future tech projects.

Answer (score -2):

To check whether the origin of the given POST message is legitimate user or not, you should consider the **authentication** of the message. There can be various ways to achieve the authentication, but common way is to use **token** that is issued when sign up or login process. If the post message contains valid token, we can regard that the message is sent from valid user and otherwise is not a valid request. Recently **JWT** is widely used for web application. These sites may be helpful: [JWT.io](https://jwt.io), [JWT - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_Web_Token)

In this case, if attackers can capture and modify your POST message, then the your scheme fails. To prevent this attack scenario, you need to encrypt your message. As you say, if you hardcode the secret key on the client side app, attackers can know the key by analyzing the client side app. So the better way is to encrypt the message by using **the public key of the server**. Public key is only for the encryption and it is computationally impossible to decrypt message using the public key. Decryption is done by private key which should be securely stored in the server.

These public key and private key based encryption methods are called public key cryptosystem (PKC). For instance, RSA and ECC are most well-known public key crypyosystem.

For the web application, HTTPS protocol is provided. You can encrypt your POST message using HTTPS.

Note that **Encryption** itself doesn't provide integrity and authentication. Encryption just *hide* the message, but not guarantee that the message is sent from the valid user.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I don't want to do login/signup process. My question is when someone open my app, I want him to access "public data" but don't want other website (for exemple) to post or get my data. So in my PHP, I need to validate infos came from **my** application.

Comment: So, what you really want to do is to authenticate **your app**, not **a user**. You don't need login process, but you just want to prove the message is sent from your app, not from other apps.

Comment: In that case, I think the simplest way is to use a client ID or a client key, which is a randomly generated string. Generate a client ID and register the client ID to your server when the first running of your app, and the server stores the client ID into database. When your app sends a POST request to the server, include the client ID to verify the client. For integrity check, you can also include message digest using hash function.

Comment: Still the POST request is in plaintext, so if there is an attacker on the network, then she can sniff the client ID. To prevent this situation, use HTTPS. To manage your client ID securely in your app on user's device, store your client ID to secure storage e.g., iOS keychain or Android keystore. If your server detects a suspicious POST request, then you can remove corresponding client ID.

Comment: I strongly advise against shoehorning JWT in as a solution where it's not even relevant, and also [against using JWT at all](https://paragonie.com/blog/2017/03/jwt-json-web-tokens-is-bad-standard-that-everyone-should-avoid) unless you're forced to.